# New SSL certificate not working on the Google Cloud Platform

Tags: ssl, google-cloud-platform, ssl-certificate

I recently installed a new self managed certificate on the Google Cloud Platform. This is be cause the old one was out of date. I believe that I have done this correctly.

```
sgnapper@cloudshell:~ (tactical-curve-284112)$ gcloud compute ssl-certificates list \
--global

NAME: eris-sypro
TYPE: SELF_MANAGED
CREATION_TIMESTAMP: 2022-06-23T06:32:33.689-07:00
EXPIRE_TIME: 2023-06-22T16:59:59.000-07:00
MANAGED_STATUS:
```

Yet I get:

Your connection isn't private
Attackers might be trying to steal your information from syproltd.co.uk (for example, passwords, messages or credit cards).
NET::ERR_CERT_REVOKED

When I try and connect to the site.

I am not familiar with Google Cloud and I wonder if there is a step I have missed.

If anybody can help, I would be grateful.

Comment: You cannot use a certificate that has been revoked **NET::ERR_CERT_REVOKED**.

Answer (score 0):

`gcloud compute ssl-certificates create` does not automagically provision the SSL certificate to any services, but only adds it to the infrastructure. `NET::ERR_CERT_DATE_INVALID` expired 9 days ago. And the new one likely isn't provisioned to the load balancer. This is being explained here: [Step 3: Associate an SSL certificate with a target proxy](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/ssl-certificates/self-managed-certs#associate-target-proxy). When the certificate is installed on a VM instance (no load balancer), you may run `gcloud compute ssl-certificates delete eris-sypro --global` and instead replace the SSL certificate installed on the VM instance.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I don't have a load balancer and I deleted the certificate and loaded a new one. How do I then provision the SSL certificate to the VM Instance. I am not sure of the command to do that.

sgnapper@cloudshell:~ (tactical-curve-284112)$ gcloud compute ssl-certificates list
NAME: eris--sypro-jun-22
TYPE: SELF_MANAGED
CREATION_TIMESTAMP: 2022-06-25T09:12:41.207-07:00
EXPIRE_TIME: 2023-06-22T16:59:59.000-07:00
MANAGED_STATUS:

Comment: You cannot provision Google Managed certificates to VMs. When @martinzeitler mentioned about setting the cert in the VM he was referring to set your own certificate and not one from Google

Comment: Let me outline the full context.

1. The original self managed was working fine until the certificate expired
2. The original certificate was revoked and a new one was created
3. The new certificate was uploaded to Google Cloud
4. I am missing the final step to provision this in the VM Instance I am using

That is where I am looking for help. What step do I take after having uploaded the new certificate to the platform.

Thank you.

Comment: Use SSH or Cloud Shell to overwrite the expired certificate file with the new one. That's it.

Comment: Sorry to be stupid but how do I overwrite the certificate. I thought I had done that by deleting the old and installing the new. The new certificate has the correct date but it hasn't changed the outcome.

Comment: When finding it difficult with a Linux shell, use a SFTP program with a GUI; it's just copy/paste.